# Exclude values in a rolling average (dropping the high and low values) partition by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, rolling-computation

I'm attempting to calculate a rolling average over 6 weeks where I drop the high sales week and the lows sales week in that specific time frame.

I've used windows functions to identify the high and low sales weeks, but I'm having trouble running an average across that 6 week window and excluding the high and lows.

I've attempted a case statement within the avg function but it's returning the wrong result.

Here is my code:

```
;with average_daily_sales
as
(
select sum(SalesUnits) as total_sales_units, 
ItemNumber, 
Store, 
END_OF_WEEK,
BEGIN_OF_WEEK
from CONFORM_MOVEMENT
where Store = 10 and ItemNumber =1026295
group by ItemNumber, Store, END_OF_WEEK, BEGIN_OF_WEEK


)

--USING windows function to accomplish a 6 week rolling average to identify the high and low selling weeks
--PARTITION BY creates pairs of stores and item numbers to analyze per each window (6 records represent 6 weeks)
--Set the window being analyzed by replacing the integer value between "ROWS BETWEEEN N PRECEEDING"
,highs_lows_identifier
as
(

select
max(total_sales_units) 
    over (PARTITION BY Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
            ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as highs,
min(total_sales_units) 
    over (PARTITION BY Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
            ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as lows,
Store,
ItemNumber,
END_OF_WEEK,
BEGIN_OF_WEEK,
total_sales_units
from average_daily_sales
group by Store, ItemNumber, END_OF_WEEK, BEGIN_OF_WEEK, total_sales_units


)
--Remove highs and lows from their respective record
,remove_highs_and_lows
as
(
select          
        avg(case when total_sales_units = highs 
                        or total_sales_units = lows
                        then null else total_sales_units end) 
            over ( partition by Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
                    rows between 5 preceding and current row) as average_sales_units,

        Store,
        ItemNumber,
        BEGIN_OF_WEEK,
        END_OF_WEEK,
        highs,
        lows,
        total_sales_units,
        total_sales_units /7 as daily_sales_units
from highs_lows_identifier
)

select * from remove_highs_and_lows
order by END_OF_WEEK asc
```

Results Image:

[image]

Expectation: average_sales_units in record 19 should be 61.5 (excluding record 16 and 17). however, the exclusion isn't occuring and my result is 64. This logic should occur in every record (example record 18 average_sales_units should exclude record 16 and 13).

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff should I attach an excel file with the data and my results? Sorry thought the image and explanation at the end would suffice

Comment: . . No.  You should add a few rows of sample data into the question as a text table.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is probably `apply`.  This makes some assumptions about what the data looks like, but the idea is:

```
select cm.*, rolling_avg_sales
from CONFORM_MOVEMENT cm outer apply
     (select avg(cm2.sales) as rolling_avg_sales
      from (select cm2.*,
                   row_number() over (order by sales desc) as seqnum_asc,
                   row_number() over (order by sales desc) as seqnum_desc
            from CONFORM_MOVEMENT cm2
            where cm2.store = cm.store and cm2.item = cm.item and
                  cm2.end_of_week <= cm.end_of_week and
                  cm2.end_of_week > dateadd(week, -5, cm.end_of_week)
           ) cm2
      where 1 not in (seqnum_desc, seqnum_asc)
     ) cm2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon - again apologize for not providing the sample data, but you got my mind moving and I think I was over complicating this solution.

Given that I can identify the highs and lows in the rolling 6 weeks with my window function I can simply total that rolling 6 weeks, subtract the high and low, divide by 4 to get the weekly average, and then by 7 to get the daily average.

To adhere to the business logic I will ignore the first 6 weeks as the weeks before don't have a 6 week time span to use.

Here it is:

```
--Remove highs and lows from their respective record - subtracting highs and lows to get the average
,remove_highs_and_lows
as
(
select
    --case
    --  when highs = lows then END_OF_WEEK
    --  when highs = total_sales_units 
    --      or lows = total_sales_units then END_OF_WEEK else null end as is_highs_lows,
        
        ((sum(total_sales_units)
            over ( partition by Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
                    rows between 5 preceding and current row) - highs - lows) / 4)
                    / 7 as daily_sales_units,
        sum(total_sales_units)
            over ( partition by Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
                    rows between 5 preceding and current row) as total_weekly_sales_units,
        (sum(total_sales_units)
            over ( partition by Store, ItemNumber ORDER BY END_OF_WEEK
                    rows between 5 preceding and current row) - highs - lows) / 4 as avg_weekly_sales_units,
        total_sales_units,
        highs,
        lows,
        Store,
        ItemNumber,
        BEGIN_OF_WEEK,
        END_OF_WEEK
from highs_lows_identifier

)

select * from remove_highs_and_lows
```